# using visual studio 2019 how can I clone github repos for c++ code that have no solution and build and run them?

Tags: c++, github, build, cloning

I am new to both visual studio 2019 and github. I am attempting to obtain a code from the github cloud and run it on my laptop.

Currently I have been able to clone the github repo for the source code and create a new branch. However the github repo has only c.pp files and .h files, and no project or solution files. Is this because whilst the code is written in c++ the creater did not make the code on the visual studio IDE. Either way my main issue is that every time I open it in my visual studios I do not have the build tab option available and therefore I cannot run

How can I build and run this code?
I have tried to copy and paste the code into a new project that has template solution files but it seems to defeat the point of cloning from github if i then just copy the cloned code files into a local project and this also seemed to fail when I attempted to build and run it.
For reference I am attempting to clone the following public github repo:

https://github.com/sarahtattersall/Enigma-Machine

Please advice me on the best approach thank you kindly.
Ikiro.

Comment: If the owner of the repo has not created project or solution files then I don't see any alternative to creating them yourself. Of course there is no guarantee that the code is buildable with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Does this mean that in the case of github repos where the creator has not included project or solution files for visual studios the only way to run such code on visual studios is to copy and past code into a new personal project?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I expect that you can create the project files in the cloned github repo. But I don't really know.

Comment: It's qt code so you'd probably be better off using qt creator, either way you need to create a project and add the files to it

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except the maker DID make the origina C++ program in Visual Studio, but there is still no .sln file. I believe it WOULD build if I could copy it into a new project, but I don't even know how to do that. It has a bunch of folders and subfolders containing various files - after cloning these locally, how would I import them into a new VS cpp solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a few years old by now. But you can build your own visual studio solutions from source code if you use premake or cmake. The standard is cmake but i prefer using premake personally cuz it’s just a short Lua script and you just run the premake executable in the directory. Cmake has their whole own syntax that will take some time to learn.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).